# Explanation of Permission Bits

Tags: c, linux, posix, gnu

I was looking at the permission bits used in various functions like `stat()` and `chmod()`, and I wanted a description of what the macros defined actually are. For instance `S_IRUSR` says it's represented by `00400` (GNU/Linux). My question is, could someone describe what the `00400` actually is? Is it a number, what? I understand how to OR the macros, I just don't get what the macro actually is.

Comment: [The ultimate explanation.](http://google.com/search?q=unix+permissions+bitmask)

Comment: I actually understand what the permissions are, that's not the issue, I just want to know what the number represented by the macro is and how it works. Is it a bitfield or something, I'm just trying to understand that conceptually. I understand octal permission modes, that's not the question, what does the number represent in the macro.

Comment: @Holden - "00400" is a number.  An octal (base 8) number (you can tell by the leading "0").  Representing [filesystem permissions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions).

Comment: @paulsm4 Okay, that's what I was actually asking, I didn't understand what the number was, so when you do things like 00400 |= 00200 you get 00600, but why? I thought you could only do 0 and 1 with bitwise?

Comment: Hmpf. Everything is bits. in octal representation, the bits forming a word are grouped in groups of 3 bits, and these 3 bits can then be represented by numbers 0..7 (octal means that 8 dec is 10 in octal, like 10 dec is 10 in dec :-). So if you or 4 oct with 2 oct, that means you or 100 bin with 010 bin, which yields 110 bin, which translates into 6 oct. Want more confusion?

Comment: @pbhd: Actually I think you answered my question. Admittedly, I phrased my question poorly, but you answered what I wanted. Thanks for the response.

Comment: Don't forget that computer scientists are confused about Halloween and Christmas because Oct 31 = Dec 25.

Comment: @JonathanLeffler, that's a good example, thanks :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am going to describe the left most three numbers in permission and that would also explain about S_IRUSR,

So each of the numbers is an octal number. Each number could be from 0 to 7. Each octal number could be converted to 3-bit binary number. Each bit represents a permission.

```
Left most bit = Read permission
Middle bit    = Write permission
Right most bit= Execute permission
```

Lets write 0 to 7 into binary and see the permission bits:

```
Octal    Binary 
0        0 0 0 (No Read,  No Write,  No Execute) -- No permission
1        0 0 1 (No Read,  No Write,  Yes you can execute)
2        0 1 0 (No Read,  Can Write, No execute)
3        0 1 1 (No Read,  Can Write, Can execute)
4        1 0 0 (Can Read, No Write,  No Execute)
5        1 0 1 (Can Read, No Write,  Can execute)
6        1 1 0 (Can Read, Can Write, No execute)
7        1 1 1 (Can Read, Can Write, Can execute)
```

So each number represents permissions. Now next part is for who these pemmissions are.
Let the left most three number be XYZ:
Now,

```
X means permission given to the owner of the file.
Y means permission given to the group of the owner.
Z means permission given to all other users in system , outside of user's group.
```

Given that, Z_ISUSR = 00400, now 4 means readable by user IRUSR = Is Readable by user.

These three are the important numbers in permissions, and these only specify the permissions given to the file.

Comment: Thanks for the octal - binary chart, I found that helpful.

Answer (score 0):

Wiki has very good explanations [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Filesystem_permissions)

From the linked page:

```
0 --- no permission
1 --x execute
2 -w- write
3 -wx write and execute
4 r-- read
5 r-x read and execute
6 rw- read and write
7 rwx read, write, and execute
```